# How to do a Hbase bulk delete?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We can inject data into a hbase table using these commands

> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv
>
> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles

Is there any method to do a bulk delete like this?

Comment: what do you mean bulk delete ? Delete some rows or complete data on table ? if you want to delete all data you can truncate table.

Comment: delete some rows. Think of a table which has names,ages,etc of students.
i want to delete the rows which have the age as 20. how to do that? Is it possible ?

Comment: you should know row ids, and send Delete command for every row&column qualifier. To make it fast you can send Delete commands in bulk, like 1000 at a time with java api, which gets a list of Delete operations.

Comment: could u plz explain me how to do that. I'm new to to this hbase thing